# deleting a selected element in Longlistselector?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing my first app on windows phone,I have an LongListSelector which cotains 3 elements, 2 elements are images and a textblock.Now I am able to populate the LongListSelector items,but i need to delete some items whenever its not required in the List

Items are removed based on whether we click on the image. My code is as shown.

```
  <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" DataContext="{Binding listData}" IsGroupingEnabled="False" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image Name="condition" Source="{Binding Imagetype}" Height="100"  />
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" TextWrapping='Wrap' Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="30"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Temp}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                                       FontSize="30"
                                       ></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2">
                            <Image Name="Button" Source="{Binding Remove}" Height="100" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

I need to remove the entire element from the List whenever the user clicks on Image with NAME=Button, Kindly Help me out in doing this as I am Pretty new to this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  SelectionChanged event and do like below to get selected item.

```
private void MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
     {
        YourListItemObject item = e.AddedItems[0] as YourListItemObject;
        YourMainList.Remove(item);
     }

}
```

**EDITED:**

```
private void Button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
   YourListItemObject data = (YourListItemObject)element.DataContext;
  YourMainList.Remove(data);
}
```

Comment: @sajeetharan....But will that allow me to remove the element on basis of the clicking the image.I want to remove elements only when user clicks on that image which is within the listselector

Comment: @dhee yes it will, if not add the same code to your button click , let me know if it does not work

Comment: @Sajeetharan...Its Working But not in the way as i wanted, a small help,I need the element to get deleted only when i click on the Image with Name=Button,But in this case its getting deleted every time when I click on any element,Please Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: then add the event for button click and private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   YourListItemObject obj = (YourListItemObject)((Button)sender);
   YourMainList.Remove(obj);  }

Comment: I tried but it isn't working,actual its not a button its an image and I am using Tap event within it but its throwing error....